# How to get a direction on the same train line?

Tags: c#, directions

Can you help me with step by step logic that I need to get a direction on the same train line. with already having common train line with functions Next and Previous.

```
public IStation Next(IStation s)
{
    if (!_stations.Contains(s))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var index = _stations.IndexOf(s);
    var isLast = index == _stations.Count -1;
    if (isLast)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return _stations[index + 1];
}

public IStation Previous(IStation s)
{
    if (!_stations.Contains(s))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var index = _stations.IndexOf(s);
    var isFirst = index == 0;
    if (isFirst)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return _stations[index - 1];
}
```

And my function where I look for direction.

```
public string GetLineDirectiom(Station from, Station to, Line commonLine)
{
    bool fromNextTo = true;


    //to.Lines.Count();
    //to.ToString();
    var Final = commonLine.Next(from);
    while (Final != null)
    {

    }

    if (fromNextTo)
        return "next";
    else return "previous";
}
```

Comment: What is the `Line commonLine`?

Comment: you do a double job when you are checking _stations.Contains and _stations.IndexOf. If station cannot be found IndexOf will return -1. Please fix it :)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Apparently, an instance of a `Line` class that contains the `Next` and `Previous` methods from the first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to "visit the stations along `commonLine`", starting at the `from` station.

The loop you have started is a valid start to that end; you need a variable to store the station you are currently visiting. Maybe the current variable name `Final` is a bit confusing to yourself here, because it is not the "final" station of the line, just the one you are currently visiting.

Therefore, let's name the variable `currentStation`. Then, you want to go to the next station until you have found `to` (and thereby know the direction), or until you have reached the end of the line:

```
var currentStation = from;
while (currentStation != null)
{
    if (currentStation == to)
    {
        return "next";
    }
    currentStation = commonLine.Next(currentStation);
}
```

Now, this checks whether `to` is "ahead". If it wasn't, you can proceed to checking whether it can be found in the other direction, again starting at `from`:

```
currentStation = from;
while (currentStation != null)
{
    if (currentStation == to)
    {
        return "previous";
    }
    currentStation = commonLine.Previous(currentStation);
}
```

If this loop doesn't find `to` either, apparently `to` is not on the line. Treat this case according to your preference.

Some remarks:

- Indicating the direction as "next" or "previous" may be a bit misleading. If it really is the direction of the line, think about something like "forward" and "backward", as "next" and "previous" indeed imply the direct next/previous elements in a list.
- While the above works, I do note that your `Line` object already has the stations in an indexed list. Therefore, a simpler way of achieving your goal might be to just determine the indices of the `from` and `to` stations on `commonLine` and compare which one is greater than the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do and why you are returning string "next" and "prev" as a direction but in general to get the direction by the two stations:

```
    public int GetStationIndex(IStation s)
    {
        var index = _stations.IndexOf(s);
        if (index == -1)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return index ;
    }


    public string GetLineDirection(Station from, Station to, Line commonLine)
    {
       var direction = commonLine.GetStationIndex(from)<commonLine.GetStationIndex(to)?"next" : "previous" 
       return direction;
    }
```